# Temporary E-mail Addresses in Business

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam

I'm a big fan of services like [mailnull](http://mailnull.com/) which allow users to give a temporary e-mail address to prevent spam.

I'd like to give something like this to my users.

Does anyone know of any solutions that would work with Exchange 2010, my current environment?

Comment: For a business, you should be using a proper spam filter, and using mail for business purposes. Using a mail "obfuscator" will only add confusion to your recipients who are expecting email from a proper business name.

Comment: I don't mean to confuse actual recipients, but I think that there is a difference between a legitimate email communication and newsletters/marketing materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Exchange will handle this, but I enabled user suffixes.  I use a different suffix for each newsletter, marketer, etc.   Instead of `user@example.com`, is use `user.marketer@example.com`.  If one of these addresses becomes a spam source I create an alias that fails delivery. The alias i use is `:fail: Unroutable addess`.

Users can create as many aliases as needed this way, and legitimate email is delivered.  Blocking addresses is relatively easy.  You will need to check how to implement both the suffix and alias mechanism in Exchange.  Aliases need to be checked before suffixes are removed for this to work.

Comment: Did you create a web interface for users to set their aliases to fail? or do you do it manually each time?

Comment: Currently, we do it manually.  It hasn't needed to be done often, and allows me to track which organizations are leaking addresses.  If I were to provide an web interface, I would likely use an LDAP store.  It might be useful to instruct the users to use the domain name as a suffix.